# Query to select records at every 1 Km distance from a table containing Lat, Long and speed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2005 database. Can I get some help to write a query to select records at every 1 Km distance from a table of driving data containing the following columns:

```
timestamp                 lat       long        speed MPH
---------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-10 22:10:16.000   33.91985  -84.34022   4
2017-03-10 22:10:20.000   33.91985  -84.34031   5
2017-03-10 22:10:23.000   33.91985  -84.34035   5
2017-03-10 22:10:26.000   33.91985  -84.34048   7
2017-03-10 22:10:27.000   33.91985  -84.34048   7
2017-03-10 22:10:30.000   33.91985  -84.34062   9
2017-03-10 22:10:31.000   33.91985  -84.34062   9
2017-03-10 22:10:34.000   33.91986  -84.3408    8
2017-03-10 22:10:35.000   33.91986  -84.3408    8
```

If the total distance travelled is 10.6 Kms then 11 records will be selected from the table including the first and the last record in the timestamp order.

Comment: Speed in Miles per hour or kilometers per hour?

Comment: Miles per hour.

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward solution is calculate distance at each row (compared with some anchor row) using `Geography.STDistance()` in `WHILE` loop

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stdistance-geography-data-type

The next step is use geography datatype instead of lat/lon columns.

Comment: I have thought about it too. In sqlserver 2005 I don't have spatial. I am looking for a haversine formula solution for each consecutive records. Then add up till the sum is 1 km. But I doubt if it will be efficient. Thanks anyway Mikhail.